# Spring not using log4j2.xml configuration over slf4j

Tags: java, spring, maven, slf4j, log4j2

I'm updating one of my applications to Log4J2 over SLF4J and I'm running into troubles with Spring.

Additionally to the "normal" (correct) logging output

```
2013-05-24 20:02:00,490 INFO  [main] application.Application (Application.java:33) - Application started with arguments []
```

I'm getting lines like this

```
Mai 24, 2013 8:02:00 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@5dfb3d5c: startup date [Fri May 24 20:02:00 CEST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
```

on System.err, so spring is not logging using my Log4J2 configuration.

These are my configuration files:

**pom.xml**

```xml
<slf4j.version>1.7.4</slf4j.version>
<log4j.version>2.0-beta6</log4j.version>

...

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>${log4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>${log4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    <version>${log4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

**log4j2.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appenders>
        <File name="file" fileName="error.log" append="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%t %-5p %c{2} - %m%n"/>
        </File>
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
        </Console>
    </appenders>
    <loggers>
        <root level="all">
            <appender-ref ref="file"/>
            <appender-ref ref="console"/>
        </root>
        <logger name="org.springframework" level="error">
            <appender-ref ref="file"/>
            <appender-ref ref="console"/>
        </logger>
    </loggers>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spring uses `commons-logging` framework for logging. So you should exclude `commons-logging` dependency from Spring using Maven exclusion and add maven dependency to `jcl-over-slf4j`

Comment: Does this really work? Log4j2 documentation specifically states that you should not remove the commons dependencies when using the jcl bridge... or is this something different entirely? http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/maven-artifacts.html